# Calculating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sin{\frac{1}{n}}$ by the squeeze theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I've been having a bit of trouble with a tutorial question from my 3rd year Foundations of Calculus course.

It asks to find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sin{\frac{1}{n}}$ using the pinching theorem. I know the limit must be 0, but I'm not quite sure how to get there using the theorem.

I've got to $\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sin{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ but can't see a clear way to go from there to just $\sin{\frac{1}{n}}$.

This may be because I've been staring at it too long and am missing something obvious, so it would be lovely if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the question is actually $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin{\frac{1}{n}}$, not $\frac{1}{n}\sin{\frac{1}{n}}$ (sorry, I realise that was a little confusing ...)

Comment: There is a very useful inequality: $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit removing the tag "algebra-precalculus" and adding the tag "calculus", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2004292).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
 $$\sin x\le x \ \ \forall x>0$$ and $$\sin x\ge x\ \ \forall x<0$$

Or in other words: $$|\sin x|\le |x|$$

You can use $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\ \ \Big ( -h\le \sin h \le h \Big)$$

Comment: Ah gosh, I knew it was something horribly simple! My excuse is I'm a physics student and haven't done pure math for at least 2 years :P.

Comment: It's ok , though simple sometimes We get stuck if mind is exhausted or we are not in touch.

Comment: you should add some absolute values else both inequalites are wrong

Comment: @vim See this for information about $\sin{\dfrac1n}$ :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+sin%281%2Fn%29

Comment: @Ju'x I already told him that his inequalites are wrong when he doesn't use absolute values, but seems like he don't care

Comment: Improved. :p . Silly mistake.

Comment: @exploringnet in the last inequality you shouldn't write a limit on one side and not on the others part of the inequality. And in the last inequality you only need the case for $h>0$, you should mention it or use absolut values again. Sorry I am annoying :(

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Hope you are now satisfied !

Answer (score 2):

If $n>\frac{2}{\pi}$, $0<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\pi}{2}$ hence $0<\sin(\frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}$.

As $n\to \infty$, $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$.
Thus, by the squeeze theorem $\sin\dfrac1n\to0$

Comment: How you got from first range of 1/n to sin(1/n)<1/n  ?

Comment: $\sin(x)<x$ for $x>0$. You can convince yourself by looking at the graph for `large' x and looking at the taylor expansion near $0$ for instance.

Comment: I'm assuming by taking the sine of both sides? Thanks, this is a cool way to do it that I wouldn't have thought of straight away.

Comment: That's what i have used in my solution. But what you have done in 1st line after $0<1/n<\pi/2$ to go to $0<sin(1/n)<1/n$ How? @vim  By taking sine on both side we get $0<sin(1/n)<1$

Comment: Ah yes of course, sorry. Clearly I shouldn't be doing this past midnight ...

Comment: I don't really see the problem: $\frac{1}{n}>0$ implies $\sin(\frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\pi}{2}$ implies $\sin(\frac{1}{n})>0.$

Comment: @Abel But $1/n \le \pi/2 \ \not \to \ sin(1/n)\le 1/n$

Comment: No, but I don't think I ever claimed that. I'm sorry if I gave the impression that this was my argument.

Comment: Ofcource it did . You wrote $1/n \le \pi/2 \ \ $ **HENCE** $\ \ \sin(1/n)\le 1/n$

Comment: No. I wrote $0<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\pi}{2}$ **HENCE** $0<\sin(\frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}$. Which is true.

Comment: What is the intermediate step? Hence? I can't get this . You have not taken sine on each side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8219/discussion-between-exploringnet-and-abel)

Comment: By the way, for $n\geq 1$, the implication $1/n \leq \pi/2 \implies \sin(1/n)\leq 1/n$ is true!

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not exactly the squeeze theorem (at least not in the first step) but we notice that when  we set $x=\frac{1}{n}$ that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+ } f(x)$$
So we see that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \sin(x)$$
And here we can use that  for $x>0$.
$$-x\leq \sin(x)\leq x$$

The substitution is surely not necessary, but I think using the substitution makes it clearer.

Comment: Of course, the equality $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+ } f(x)$$ is false: take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ as counter-example.

Comment: Dominic the 1/n is  obviously wrong.

Comment: oh lol yeah the $\frac{1}{n}$ is bullshit  sry for that wanted to write something else first i gonna fix that

Comment: @exploringnet fixed it

Comment: @user70123 fixed and thanks again i should proofread my proofs ;)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sin x=_0O(x)$ so
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|\leq\frac{C}{n}$$

Comment: Hey OP know this but he want to use Sandwich rule.

Comment: @exploringnet You're right I misread the question.

Comment: Yes. you did read wrong.